# Determine Heating costs in $/kWh for a specific location

Tags: heating-systems, energy

Suppose I wanted to find the average heating price for a specific location in the US, where:

> *heating_price*: The price of equivalent unit energy intensity of heating energy source (e.g. natural gas), measured in $/kWh.

Is there a public API that would return such information for either residential, commercial or industrial spaces? After doing my own research I am able to find electricity costs/general energy costs but am unable to find endpoints or data specific to heating.

Disclaimer: I apologize if this is the wrong Q/A forum to ask in advance. If you could please redirect me to the proper site/SE site that would be helpful.

Comment: Check out heating degree days

Comment: For residential heating, check out [RECS](https://www.eia.gov/consumption/residential/data/2015/). For commercial, check out [CBECS](https://www.eia.gov/consumption/commercial/data/2012/).

Comment: Regarding site recommendation, [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) is good for general data resource questions, and [Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) is good for questions about energy.

Comment: @LShaver Thank you for the site recommendations

Comment: you can't find natural gas or home heating oil prices?

Comment: @TigerGuy I can find natural gas prices but it doesn't imply it's being used for heating. Gas-powered air conditioning units, cooking etc..

Comment: Just calculate the heating requirement and then convert to the price of any relevant fuel.

Comment: @Jebathon, the price for natural gas is the same no matter what it's used for.  It all comes out of the same pipe.

Comment: @TigerGuy ah I see thanks for clarifying